# O que significa uma versão SNAPSHOT?

Tags: spring, maven, versionamento

Uma versão `SNAPSHOT` seria semelhante a uma versão BETA?

Trabalho com **Maven** e como padrão ele cria os arquivos WARs como `MeuProjeto-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war`.

Se minha versão ainda não é uma versão `1.0.0` qual o sentido da palavra SNAPSHOT? Não seria o mesmo que `0.0.1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma versão snapshot no Maven é aquela que não foi lançada, é a compilação do seu código em um determinado momento.

Com isso, é possível ter a versão 1.0-snapshot, antes que a versão 1.0 "real" seja lançada, ou seja, é uma versão ainda em desenvolvimento.

Como a versão snapshot ainda está em desenvolvimento, ela pode receber atualizações, logo a versão 1.0-snapshot de hoje pode ser diferente de ontem ou de amanhã.

> Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901378/what-exactly-is-a-maven-snapshot-and-why-do-we-need-it